# How to properly set a textbox value in javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
 <input id='myTxt' type='text' value='hello'/>
```

javascript:

```
$("#myTxt").val('Blah'); // works

var bla = document.getElementById("myTxt"); bla.value = "Blah"; // works

$("#myTxt").value = "blah"; // doesn't work
```

Why doesn't the last example work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `$("#myTxt")` is a jQuery object with does not have anything called `value`.
What you can do is something like:

```
$("#myTxt").get(0).value = "blah";
```

Comment: so is get(0) always the way to get an html object?

Comment: no. its is an array so you can also do `$("#myTxt")[0].value`

Comment: why would my textbox be an array? isn't there a generic way to get from a jquery object to an html object?

Comment: Why would the jquery object be an array though?

Comment: @foreyez Your `$("#myTxt")` will select only one DOM object (and wrap it in a jQuery object) because the selector is a unique ID - but in general, jQuery's `$("someSelector")` can return *multiple* things, such as `$("div.collapsed")` which will select every div that has a class of "collapsed". That is why `$(...)` always returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#myTxt")` is an array of jQuery objects that wrap the selected DOM objects.

Since you're using an ID in your selector `#myTxt` you will get an array with only one element in it.

You can set the value of the selected item(s) with jQuery's `.val()` method:

```
$("#myTxt").val("blah");
```

You don't have to retrieve the underlying DOM object.